# How to compile FreeType2 for Tizen?

Tags: android, static-libraries, tizen, freetype2, tizen-native-app

I'm developing a **Native Tizen application** which requires **FreeType2** for drawing fonts.

I have searched all the documentation from http://www.freetype.org and the docs/ included in the archive from their website, but there is no info on how to do with.

I managed to build a static library for Android under Ubuntu. It works just fine on Android and I figured I could use that as well on Tizen. 
Although the application compiles and the `FT_Init_FreeType( &library ) succeeds`, it crashes on `FT_New_Face` or `FT_New_Memory_Face`.

Anyone has an idea on how I could make a static library specifically for Tizen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can use the Install.Any from the docs to make your own project in Tizen IDE and build a custom library compiled for it.